# PostgreSQL save Java Map as whole

Tags: java, postgresql

I have an Entity in Spring Boot where one of its fields is an `HashMap`. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776331/storing-a-hashmap-in-an-sql-database) but I can't use this solution, I can't have an entry for each key-value couple.
I need to have a table with a column named `id`, another one named `name`, etc... and at the same way a column with my `Map` object. Is there a way do to this?
The only solution I came up with is to convert the map in a key-value string, and then read it back to Map, but I was wondering if there's a better and more compact way to save the map as a particular type of column data in the DB.

Comment: A `jsonb` column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and to save data to db I simply convert HashMap to Json format and then save the json to the jsonb column? Like `myEntity.setHashMap(json)` and then `service.save(myEntity)` ?

Comment: you can use hstore https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-hstore-jpa-entity-property-hibernate/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe it can help someone.

As mentioned in the comments, one way is to use `jsonb` PostgreSQL type, as its structure reminds of key-value pairs.

Suppose, there is a `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();`

1. *Save jsonb value to PostgreSQL table*
   It is possible to use an `ObjectMapper` instance to convert Java objects into JSON strings:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
   String mapAsJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
   // then insert 'mapAsJson' to a jsonb-column
} catch (Exception ex) {
   ...
}
```

2. *Read jsonb value from PostgreSQL table*
   Again, we can use an instance of `ObjectMapper` to convert jsonb column to a Java object while we are reading from the table. This code can be used directly in a repository class:

```
String someJsonb = "{\"A\":\"Tom\", \"B\":\"Bella\", \"C\":\"Maria\"}";
try {
   Map<String, String> parsedMapData = mapper.readValue(someJsonb, Map.class);
} catch (Exception ex) {
   ...
}
```